Flutter Background Notification Handler Stops Working on iOS After Several Notifications
Notification always received, it's just that the handler stops working after a period of time / number of notifications.

After a certain number of notifications (around 9), the background handler stops being called.
This issue persists until an undefined period passes and the app is reopened to re-register the handler.

Does anyone have a stable background notification handling configuration for Flutter on iOS that consistently works?
Any insights or solutions to prevent the handler from stopping would be greatly appreciated.
I'm developing a Flutter app and have configured a background notification handler to perform certain tasks when a notification is received while the app is in either the background or terminated state.
After a fresh install, the handler works correctly (a test message is logged). However, after receiving a few more notifications (the limit appears random but is usually around 9), the handler stops being called, as if iOS has killed the invoking service. To get it working again, I have to wait for an unspecified period and then open the app to re-register the handler. It works again for a while until it stops, as described.
The handler is defined as a top-level function and is annotated with @pragma('vm:entry-point'). It is registered from the main method.
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  print('Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}');
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

Thanks in advance!
EDIT
There is a bug in the Flutter Firebase iOS integration that causes the main method to be called when a notification is received. This results in the entire app running in the background, which might be causing iOS to kill the handler.
Is there any workaround for this issue?

Here:
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  print('Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}');
}

you should remove this line:
 await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

because here:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

you've initialized Firebase instance already.

It didn't make a difference still stops after some notifications are sent.
I had a thought before that it could be because the handler is doing "too much work" then iOS would kill it, but I tested it with only a print statement, it didn't differ.
